# $A=\{x∈[0,1] : \text{for all } y∈[0,x] \text{ we have }f(y)≤1/2\}=[0,1]$, where $f(x) \leq \int_{0}^{x} f(y)^2 dy$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:[0,1] \to [0, \infty)$ is a non-negative continuous function so that $f(0)=0$ and for all $x \in [0,1]$ we have $$f(x) \leq \int_{0}^{x} f(y)^2 dy$$
Now consider the set $$A=\{x∈[0,1] : \text{for all  }  y∈[0,x] \text{ we have }f(y)≤1/2\}$$ Prove that $A=[0,1]$.
Since $f$ is bounded of $[0,x]$, I think $f$ may be $0$. But I am not able to do this. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: By continuity at $0$ there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(x)\leq 1/2$ for $x\in[0,\epsilon)$. By continuity at $\epsilon$ it is also true that $f(\epsilon)\leq 1/2$. Let $a$ be the supremum of all $\epsilon\in[0,1]$ such that $f(x)\leq 1/2$ for $x\in[0,\epsilon]$. Then $f(a)\leq \int_{0}^{a}f^2\leq\frac{a}{4}\leq \frac{1}{4}$. Therefore, by continuity at $a$, if $a<1$ there is $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(x)leq 1/2$ for $x\in[a,a+\epsilon)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $A$ is non-empty since $f(0) = 0$ and thus by continuity there is $\delta > 0$ so that $f(y) \le 1/2$ for all $y \in [0,\delta]$.

Take $x \in A$. Then $f(y) \le 1/2$ for all $y \in [0,x]$. But then $$f(x) \le \int^x_0 f(y)^2 dy \le \int^x_0 \frac 1 4 dy = \frac x 4 \le \frac 1 4.$$ Thus again by contiuity, there is $\delta > 0$ so that $f(y) \le 1/2$ for all $y \in [0,x+\delta]$. This shows that $(x-\delta, x+\delta) \subset A$, and thus $A$ is an open set, since for any element of $A$, we can find a ball surrounding that element that remains in $A$.

Conversely, if $x \not\in A$, then there is $y \in [0,x]$ such that $f(y) > 1/2$. But then by continuity, $f(y-\epsilon) > 1/2$ for some small $\epsilon > 0$ and this shows that $x-\epsilon \not \in A$, and thus $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon) \subset A^c$. Similar to above, this shows that $A^c$ is open, and so $A$ is closed.

Since $[0,1]$ is connected, we conclude that $A = [0,1]$, since this is the only open and closed subset of $[0,1]$.

Comment: It is $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\cap[0,1]\subset A^c$, isn't it?

Comment: Sure, I suppose $x+\epsilon$ could be larger than $1$ so to be precise, we should intersect the set with $[0,1]$, and similarly in the first part. But of course, the proof still goes through; all that matters is that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon) \cap [0,1]$ is open in the subspace topology on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @User8128 nitpicking: The empty set is the other open and closed subset.

Comment: @lzralbu I address this by first showing that $A$ is non-empty, but yes, the last sentence should also include “non-empty.”

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment that is too long to post it as a comment.

$$f(x)\le\int_0^xf(y)^2dy\le x\sup_{0\le t \le 1}f(t)^2$$

Since the supremum of $f$ is reached at some point $x=x_M$ (Weierstrass' theorem),
$$M=f(x_M)\le x_Mf(x_M)^2$$
If $M=f(x_M)=0$, the statement is obvious. Otherwise,
$$M\ge Mx_M\ge 1$$

The other answer shows that $M\le\frac12$. Thus, as you guessed, $f\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a different approach I believe also to be correct: since $f(x)\leq\int_0^xf(y)^2dy$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, we can say that $f$ is bounded from above (i.e. $f(x)\leq\bar{f}(x)$) on $[0,1]$ by a function $\bar{f}$ defined by
\begin{align}
\bar{f}(x)& = \int_0^x\bar{f}(y)^2dy,\quad\text{for all }x\in[0,1],\\
\bar{f}(0) &= 0.
\end{align}
This is an ODE for $\bar{f}$ with solution $\bar{f}(x)=(-x+c)^{-1}$. Using $\bar{f}(0)=0$, we find that
$$
\bar{f}(0)=\frac{1}{-0+c}=0\implies c\rightarrow\infty.
$$
Since $x\in[0,1], \bar{f}(x)=\lim_{c\rightarrow\infty}(-x+c)^{-1}=0$ for all $x$. Thus, $f(x)\leq0\leq1/2$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ and $A=[0,1]$.